# html new line for each line of code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a program that will output some text to a .php file but in the source code it looks like

```
59 | Hello There.
60 | I am some code.
61 | blablabla.
```

the program doesn't put a < br / > at the end of each line.

So in the browser it looks like

### Hello There.I am some code.blablabla.

Is there anyway for me to make the website display a new line for each new line of the code? so it will be correctly displayed as

### Hello There.
    I am some code.
    Blablabla.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use <br/> and /n as well

Comment: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php): _Returns string with <br /> or <br> inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r)._

Comment: Will you accept an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Other than just forcing the PHP to output with `<br>`, you could also output the whole text to `<pre>` tags.

```html
<pre>Hello There.
I am some code.
blablabla.</pre>
```

Since some browsers would style it as code, sometimes there's a need to change the font. So as not to specify font, could be done by placing that pre into a div and set the font to inherit.

```css
pre{
  font-family:inherit;  
}
```

```html
<div><pre>Hello There.
I am some code.
blablabla.</pre></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
nl2br("Hello There.
I am some code.
blablabla.");
```

OR

```
nl2br($variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

### If the code is not that long use `"\n"`

This:

```
 echo '<html>'."\n".'<head></head>'."\n".'<body></body>'."\n".'</html>';
```

Will output this:

```
 <html>  
 <head></head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

> PS: Be sure to use double quotes, `"\n"` and NOT `'\n'`